# How to map the variable from a Dataset / DataTable in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dataset

I have a Dataset which is populated from a stored procedure. The dataset is filled with the table of records.

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("usp_GetData", conn);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@servername", servername);              

        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

        da.Fill(ds);
    }
// I did a little change by populating to a DataTable. Hope LINQ query can help.
 DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table"];
```

Dataset returns two rows with 3 columns each. Each row has to be mapped with each variable.

Expected output:

```
string variable1 = value 1 from dataset where conditionparameter = 1
string variable2 = value 2 from dataset where conditionparameter = 2
```

How to map the variable from a Dataset in c#?

Comment: Since there is  only 2 rows, cant you just look at each and store the value accordingly?

Comment: I gave 2 as an example. Basically, I am populating the dataset from a config table in the SQL. Config table will be having over 15 row of records.  Depending on each server, we will be filtering and populating the records to each of these variable

Comment: Use a WHERE clause and you will get a max of two back.

Comment: Why don't you use something like **Dapper** to handle this automagically? This code to do this stuff has been written soooooooo many times already - just use something ready-made, and save yourself a lot of time! https://dapper-tutorial.net/